# gcloud compute project-info describe - Get SSH-key usernames without associated keys

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've been tasked with getting a list of all the project-level SSH keys throughout our projects and to remove those who have left our company.

In my brief search this afternoon, I've managed to get a list within a singular project using:

```
gcloud compute project-info describe --format="table(commonInstanceMetadata.items.ssh-keys)"
```

However, this provides a list of strings of usernames mixed with the ssh-rsa keys, like:

username1:ssh-rsa [proceeded by key]

username2:ssh-rsa [proceeded by key]

username2:ssh-rsa [proceeded by key]

Is there a way to separate these to get a list of *just* usernames without the rsa-ssh keys, similar to how the metadata is presented within the GCP console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Edit1

Please try with the following command:

```
gcloud compute project-info describe --format="table(commonInstanceMetadata.items.ssh-keys)"  | cut -d ":" -f 1
```

It will give you something like

```
SSH-KEYS
username1
username2
username3
```

To format only with `gcloud` is a little hard, please try with regular expression like cut or sed.

#### Edit2

Also you can find interesting the following code, it gets all the metadata user information from all your projects.

```
#!/bin/bash
for project in $(gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)")
   do
      echo "ProjectId: $project"
      for user in $(gcloud compute project-info describe --project=$project -- 
         format="table[no-heading](commonInstanceMetadata.items.ssh-keys)" | grep -v ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 | cut -d ":" -f 1)
      do
         echo " -> User $user"
   done
done
```

The output will be something like:

```
ProjectId: project-test-288915
 -> User myuser_super
ProjectId: project-test-274519
 -> User user1
 -> User user2
```

Comment: Thanks, Jose, though as you say it gives me an output of the label followed by the project name. I need the list of usernames separated from the keys.

Comment: @RobTheRobot16 Sorry, you are right, I have updated my answer, I hope it works for you.

Comment: @RobTheRobot16 I've edited again my answer to add more information, I hope you find this information useful.

Comment: Thanks, Jose! That's incredibly helpful! Thank you!